# How does the page-based model work in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am reasonably familiar with C# desktop development and am very familiar with Rails, so ASP.NET MVC makes sense to me. However, I have a more lightweight site that I want to build in a manner more akin to dropping a bunch of .php files into a hierarchy of directories and having them be served up as just HTML files run through a pre-processor. (A full MVC stack and architecture seems like overkill for what is basically a brochure site.)

I believe it is possible to do this in ASP.NET (I remember the single .aspx pages approach from back in the day), but I'm not sure what this programming model is called in order to search for info on it--I can only find references to MVC and "web forms" in newer documentation.

I also would like to use pieces that are more popularly used in MVC, but in this more simple page-based model. For example, I would like to use Razor templates (with layouts and partials) and to access a single Model object that is shared across a number of templates.

I would appreciate any advice, or info on how to find documentation on using ASP.NET in this way.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for ASP.NET Web Pages? http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that appears to be the term. Any idea how you set the Razor Model variable for a single page like this? The @model directive doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps that is somehow tied to MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASP.NET Web Pages framework](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) supports web applications built using the Web Site project type* as well as Razor layouts and partials. It does not support strongly type models in the same way as MVC.  However. that doesn't prevent you from taking a strongly typed approach to Web Pages development. The mechanism for passing data to partials is via the dynamic `Page` property (similar to `ViewBag`) which requires casting to get Intellisense support. Web Pages also lacks any kind of Model Binding support.

*This is the ASP.NET project type that does not require pre-compilation before deployment (as opposed to the Web Application project type). Web Forms apps can be built using either project type, but ASP.NET MVC apps can only be built using the Web Applications project type.